# Android OpenSL ES - issue with .wav file sampled at 44.1Khz

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, opensl

I'm trying to convert some of my *OpenAL* code to *OpenSL ES* for my Android usage *(Kitkat 4.4.4)* on *Genymotion* and encountered an issue with .wav files sampled at *44.1Khz*. My application is a *native* one (glue).

I've followed the **/native-audio** sample of *Android NDK* samples and fragments from the excellent book *Android NDK Beginners Guide*, so my code behaves correctly on most of wav/PCM data, except those sampled at 44.1Khz. My specific code is this:

**Engine init**

```
  // create OpenSL ES engine
  SLEngineOption EngineOption[] = {(SLuint32) SL_ENGINEOPTION_THREADSAFE, (SLuint32) SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE};
  const SLInterfaceID lEngineMixIIDs[] = {SL_IID_ENGINE};
  const SLboolean lEngineMixReqs[] = {SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE};
  SLresult res = slCreateEngine(&mEngineObj, 1, EngineOption, 1, lEngineMixIIDs, lEngineMixReqs);
  res = (*mEngineObj)->Realize(mEngineObj, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
  res = (*mEngineObj)->GetInterface(mEngineObj, SL_IID_ENGINE, &mEngine);   // get 'engine' interface
  // create output mix (AKA playback; this represents speakers, headset etc.)
  res = (*mEngine)->CreateOutputMix(mEngine, &mOutputMixObj, 0,NULL, NULL);
  res = (*mOutputMixObj)->Realize(mOutputMixObj, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
```

**Player init**

```
  SLresult lRes;
  // Set-up sound audio source.
  SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue lDataLocatorIn;
  lDataLocatorIn.locatorType = SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE;
  lDataLocatorIn.numBuffers = 1;   // 1 buffer for a one-time load
  // analyze and set correct PCM format
  SLDataFormat_PCM lDataFormat;
  lDataFormat.formatType = SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM;

  lDataFormat.numChannels = audio->wav.channels;     // etc. 1,2
  lDataFormat.samplesPerSec = audio->wav.sampleRate * 1000;   // etc. 44100 * 1000
  lDataFormat.bitsPerSample = audio->wav.bitsPerSample;   // etc. 16
  lDataFormat.containerSize = audio->wav.bitsPerSample;
  lDataFormat.channelMask = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER;
  lDataFormat.endianness = SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN;

  SLDataSource lDataSource;
  lDataSource.pLocator = &lDataLocatorIn;
  lDataSource.pFormat = &lDataFormat;

  SLDataLocator_OutputMix lDataLocatorOut;
  lDataLocatorOut.locatorType = SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX;
  lDataLocatorOut.outputMix = mOutputMixObj;

  SLDataSink lDataSink;
  lDataSink.pLocator = &lDataLocatorOut;
  lDataSink.pFormat = NULL;

  const SLInterfaceID lSoundPlayerIIDs[] = { SL_IID_PLAY, SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE };
  const SLboolean lSoundPlayerReqs[] = { SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE };
  lRes = (*mEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(mEngine, &mPlayerObj, &lDataSource, &lDataSink, 2, lSoundPlayerIIDs, lSoundPlayerReqs);
  if (lRes != SL_RESULT_SUCCESS) { return; }
  lRes = (*mPlayerObj)->Realize(mPlayerObj, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
  if (lRes != SL_RESULT_SUCCESS) { return; }
  lRes = (*mPlayerObj)->GetInterface(mPlayerObj, SL_IID_PLAY, &mPlayer);
  if (lRes != SL_RESULT_SUCCESS) { return; }

  lRes = (*mPlayerObj)->GetInterface(mPlayerObj, SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, &mPlayerQueue);
  if (lRes != SL_RESULT_SUCCESS) { return; }
  // register callback on the buffer queue
  lRes = (*mPlayerQueue)->RegisterCallback(mPlayerQueue, bqPlayerQueueCallback, NULL);
  if (lRes != SL_RESULT_SUCCESS) { return; }
  lRes = (*mPlayer)->SetCallbackEventsMask(mPlayer, SL_PLAYEVENT_HEADATEND);
  if (lRes != SL_RESULT_SUCCESS) { return; }

  // ..fetch the data in 'audio->data' from opened FILE* stream and set 'datasize'

  // feed the buffer with data
  lRes = (*mPlayerQueue)->Clear(mPlayerQueue);   // remove any sound from buffer
  lRes = (*mPlayerQueue)->Enqueue(mPlayerQueue, audio->data, datasize);
```

The above works good for *8000*, *22050* and *32000* *samples/sec* but on *41100* samples, 4 out of 5 times it will *repeat itself* lots of time on first play. It's like having a *door knocking* sound effect that actually loops many times (about 50 times) by a single `->SetPlayState(..SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);` and in speed. Any obvious error on my code? a multi-threaded issue with these sampling? Anyone else have this kind of problem? Should i downsample on 41.1Khz cases ? Could it be a *Genymotion* problem? tx

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downsampling from *44Khz* to *22Khz*. Interestingly, this only happens on sounds containing 1 channel and 44,100 samples; in all other cases there's no problem.